# Persistent memory confusion

Tags: c#, .net, memory, persistence, ref

I'm trying to understand persistent memory in C# and don't know why this code is not keeping the change made in one of the functions.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Test2
{
    public struct value
    {
        public int sz;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        one foo1 = new one(one_full);
        two foo2 = new two(two_full);
        make_calls(foo1, foo2);
    }

    public delegate void one(IntPtr ctx);
    public static void one_full(IntPtr ctx)
    {
        /* set sz and see if persists */
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ctx);
        value val = (value)gch.Target;

        val.sz = 6;
        Console.WriteLine("Changed sz to be 6");
    }

    public delegate void two(IntPtr ctx);
    public static void two_full(IntPtr ctx)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(ctx);
        value val = (value)gch.Target;

        Console.Write("sz is = ");
        Console.WriteLine(val.sz);
    }

    public static void make_calls(one f_one, two f_two)
    {
        value test = new value();
        test.sz = 0;

        IntPtr ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle.Alloc(test));
        f_one(ptr);
        f_two(ptr);
    }
}
```

I know it's missing the free at the end but that is just leading to messy memory management.... I'm looking for if someone can help me out and explain why sz does not stay as the value 6 for when the second function is called...

The output when ran is:

```
Changed sz to be 6
sz is = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all because `value` is a `struct`.

`GCHandle.Alloc` takes an `object` parameter, so if you pass a `struct`, it has to be boxed.

Later when you use

```
value val = (value)gch.Target;
```

it has to be unboxed, so a **copy** of it is stored in `val`. Any modifications you make later are made on the copy, not on the boxed `struct`.

It has nothing to do with `GCHandle`, it's how value types (`struct`s) work in C#. That's why it's recommended to make value types immutable.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Seems to be spot on, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase `value` is a `sturct` and structs are not reference types. when you have an instance of a struct and `var b = instanceOfStruct` then `b` is a new struct not a reference to `instanceOfStruct`. Chaning values in `b` does not reflect to `instanceOfStruct`.

In your code:

```
value val = (value)gch.Target;
```

will create a new instance of `value` struct which has same values as the structs that `gch.Target` point to it. Changing `val` does not change the struct behind `gch.Target`. The problem is because of a confusion between value types and reference types in C#. If you change `value` type to a class instead of `struct` then you will get the desired result. You can also use `dynamic` to modify the struct which is target of the handle:

```
dynamic val = gch.Target;
val.sz = 6;
```